# Writen .lua to normal .lua

Tags: lua, decoding, fivem

This is in FiveM and I dont know how to write this to 'normal' lua.

This is the code:

```
                            if LumiaM.Mfunc.Button('Give Yourself A Car (Specific)', 5, trigy) then
                                local player_id = LumiaM.Mfunc.KeyboardInput('Players ID to Recive the Car', '', 100)
                                local vehicles = LumiaM.Mfunc.KeyboardInput('Vehicle Modle', '', 100)
                                if LumiaN.natives.IsModelValid(vehicles) and LumiaN.natives.IsModelAVehicle(vehicles) then
                                    local plate = LumiaM.Mfunc.KeyboardInput('Vehicle Plate', '', 8)
                                    LumiaF.func.TriggerCustomEvent(true, "vRP:MySQL_query", "vRP/add_custom_vehicle", {user_id = player_id, vehicle = vehicles, vehicle_plate = plate, veh_type = "car"}, 2)
                                else
                                    print('Bad Model')
                                end
                            end
                            trigy = trigy + 20
                        end
```

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 1):

> This is in FiveM and I dont know how to write this to 'normal' lua

This code uses the FiveM API.

You cannot do this in Lua alone. There is no replacement for `LumiaM.Mfunc.KeyboardInput` for example.

You could replace a few things with Lua but that wouldn't actually make sense. What should be the outcome of replacing code for a game without the game?